# Let $n$ be an odd natural number , to find a continuous real valued function on $\mathbb R$ which takes every value exactly $n$ times

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $n$ be an odd natural number . We know $\mathbb R = \cup_{k \in \mathbb Z} [nk\pi , n(k+1)\pi]$ . So for every $k \in \mathbb Z$ , define

$h(x):=2k+1-(-1)^k \cos x , \forall x \in [nk\pi , n(k+1)\pi ]$ , then does the function $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ , takes

every value exactly $n$ times ? Can someone please provide any other continuous function(s) on $\mathbb R$ which takes every value exactly $n$ times for odd $n$ ? Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is a good one.  $h(x)$ needs to be defined on all of $\Bbb R$, not the interval you said.  There are many ways to modify your function to achieve the goal.  The constant $+1$ can be replaced by any value.  The whole function can be negated.  The "shape of the wave" can be changed in many ways as long as the slope stays small enough.  You need to worry about the number of times the value is achieved at the peaks.  The peaks need to line up because on one side there are two $x$ values with the same $y$ value, at the peak there is a single $x$ value nearby with that $y$ value and on the other side there are no $x$ values with that $y$ value.

Comment: But my function also is defined for whole $\mathbb R$ because I defined it for every interval $[nk\pi , n(k+1)\pi ]$ and the union of all these intervals is actually $\mathbb R$ , am I wrong ?

Comment: That is if $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is my function , then since for any $x \in \mathbb R$ , $\exists k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x \in [nk\pi , n(k+1)\pi]$ , so define $f(x):=2k+1-(-1)^k \cos x$ , I am asking whether it does take every value exactly $n$ times for odd $n$ ...

Comment: I had missed that you first picked $k$, then defined $h$ in terms of that.  I don't have an easy way to check your construction, but the idea is sound.  You match up the peaks in one interval with the valleys in the next to get the correct count of preimages.  There are many other ways to do that, but yours is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your function appears to meet the requirements.  Here is a sketch for $n=5$

[image]

Another approach without the need for intervals might be to take a sinusoidal curve and add a linear element to shift successive peaks and troughs up, perhaps something like

$$f(x)= \frac{2}{n\pi}x +\cos(x)$$

which for $n=5$ looks like

[image]

Comment: Okay , but is there any rigorous proof to show that your later function , or the function in the question does actually meet the requirement ? ( I am not talking about graphs or any special cases like $n=5$ ... )

Comment: Yes you could prove either rigorously, probably separately where the tangent is horizontal and where it is not.  Personally I find the graphs and a little thought convincing enough.

Comment: : Does $\dfrac {2x}{n \pi }-\cos x$ also works for odd $n$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev: Yes.  So too would $\dfrac {2x}{n \pi }+\sin x$ and $x-\cos \left(\dfrac{n \pi x}{2}\right)$ and many similar possibilities